# Sharepoint online 2019 simple one to many webpart?

Tags: modern-experience, 2019

How do you display a many to one list based on what is selected in a parent list on Sharepoint Online 2019?

Here is a video that shows how to do what I'm looking for in classic:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqHvAZyvX9k

I feel like this is such a simple ask, but I can't find for the life of me how to do such a simple thing.  I've already been through all the basic docs here:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-web-parts-in-sharepoint-online-b457668c-d843-4b1b-8977-a6f9228a1dec#bkmk_listproperties

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-list-web-part-ef0a1b80-f8b3-443d-b04a-1e76c70b5537

Answer (score 0):

In the Modern view, this isn't possible in SharePoint Server 2019 out of the box (and I'm not aware of any 3rd party solutions).

I would continue to use classic if this is a requirement. Or you could look at developing a SharePoint Framework webpart.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  So are you saying there is no way to present many to one relationships to users anymore?  There has to be a recommended way to implement like a "drill down" feature right?  If not, I can't see how Sharepoint is a practical tool for like 99% of any business problem..

Comment: Not in Modern SharePoint (not even in SPO, yet). You can still use classic mode SharePoint pages, even on a Modern site.

Answer (score 0):

Just like Trevor said, SharePoint 2019 modern experience does not support such functionality by default. You can post your thought in [UserVoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/) to MS.

The workarounds available will be add a wiki page which support classic web parts and just follow the steps in the video you provide.